# Add Date & Time to Database Entry

Tags: mysql, database, forms, phpmyadmin

How do i add a column to show the date and time of the database entry in a mySQL database?

I have a form that automatically stores into a database, do i need to add hidden inputs in the forms to grab the date and time or is there a specific function on the mySQL setup i can put to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your table to put the timestamp of when the record was entered or last edited.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Create a column with type TIMESTAMP and DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: thanks and how do you set database time zone? or is it already set to whatever computer accesses it?

Comment: It stamps with the clock on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table
   `your_table`
add column `created` timestamp not null default current_timestamp
```

Now all inserted rows will have an additional column namned `created` with the timestamp from creation.

Comment: this goes in the form code or can i just manually add the column in the database menu?

Comment: @user1532944 - You run it as a SQL query, it does not go in the form.